# Jasper Grouping without getting sorted data

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have a Java beans data source which returns a Collection vector.
I have added fields in random order.
Example-

```
vector.add(1,x);
vecort.add(8,x);
vector.add(2,y);
vector.add(3,z);
vector.add(4,x);
```

And i'm grouping based on alphabet. It returns

Group: x
1 
8

Group : y
2

Group : z
3

Group : x
4

Problem: **I want 4 to be grouped with x** based on char/str matching and not order based. Hence it should show Group x 1,8,4

Comment: You should post the small sample to reproduce the problem: small and minimal *jrxml* + Java code

Comment: Try adding the group field ("alphabet") as a sort field.  Groups do not reorder records, they just group together records with repeating values.

Comment: @dada67 yes but if the data is not one after the other i.e on the next immediate row it will form a new group and therefore you will have duplicate group names.

Comment: Sure @alex Will do.